# Enviar un File a través de POST con Fetch

Tags: nodejs, fetch, multer, formdata

Estoy tratando de enviar un archivo a través de fetch en Node.js. Para ello, estoy usando la dependencia multer para enviar un multipart/form-data.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const fs = require('fs');  

createProblem(authorUsername, title, alias, source, isPublic, validator, timeLimit, problemContents, userToken){
    const urlProblemCreate= 'https://example.com/api/problem/create';
    var formData = new FormData();          

    formData.append('author_username', authorUsername);    
    formData.append('title', title);    
    formData.append('problem_alias', alias);    
    formData.append('source', source);    
    formData.append('public', isPublic);    
    formData.append('validator', validator);    
    formData.append('time_limit', timeLimit);    
    formData.append('problem_contents', fs.createReadStream('/uploads/' + problemContents.filename + '.zip'));

    return fetch(urlProblemCreate ,{                
        method: 'post', 
        body: formData,        
    })
    .then((response) => {        
        return response.json();                
    });
}
```

La función es llamada desde aquí:

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

router.post('/create-problem', upload.single('problemContents'), function(req, res) {
        const params = req.body;

        const authorUsername = params.authorUsername;
        const title = params.title;
        const alias = params.alias;
        const source = params.source;
        const isPublic = params.isPublic;
        const validator = params.validator;
        const timeLimit = params.timeLimit; 
        const problemContents = req.file;                                                                                         


        createProblem(authorUsername, title, alias, source, isPublic, validator, timeLimit, problemContents, userToken)
            .then((json)=> {                                

                return res.status(200).send({
                    status: json.status,
                    uploaded_files: json.uploaded_files                    
                });                
            });                                                        
    }
```

Pero al mandarlo se queda esperando por una respuesta. ¿Que podría ser? ¿Tengo algún error en el código o hay algo que no estoy considerando? De antemano, gracias.

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. El retraso puede ser por muchos motivos que no son necesariamente evidentes con el código que has puesto Si está tardando en responder puede ser porque se ha recibido la petición, pero hay algo mal en el servidor ,por ejemplo, hay un problema de código, o se está depurando el código y está en un breakpoint, o el servidor está tardando en acceder a un recurso como una bbdd o un fichero,,. Por otra parte puede ser un problema del cliente, por ejemplo, no hay conectividad desde tu cliente hasta el servidor y se queda esperando, o la URL está mal puesta...

Comment: ¿Podrías descartar algunos de estos problemas para que se pueda acotar un poco más donde puede estar el problema?

Comment: Hola! Gracias por responder. Tengo otras funciones donde se pide peticiones al mismo servidor y responden inmediatamente. Donde tengo problema es en la parte donde mando el archivo que es en `problemContents` que debe recibir un archivo de tipo **.zip**  y hacer la petición a la API por medio del fetch. Mi duda es si es correcta esa forma de hacer la petición a través del `formData.append` o si me hace falta algo a considerar antes de mandar esta petición multiparte.